# Display the chat room collection once navigating to the chatroom

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, chat, stream-builder, chatroom

I have made a chat app which seems kind of fine except that, once user1 press user2 name to chat with the chatroom appears #empty without all the messages in the collection in firestore
The problem is >>they only appear after any user write a new message and press the send button icon
>>I need all the old messages to appear once they enter the chatroom

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "Whom" does the last `they` refer to? How shall readers interpret `user1 press user2 name to chat with the chatroom`?

Comment: As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned, please include all the information regarding your question or problem encountered.